# html anchor link not jumping far enough

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I created my Website with Webflow.
My Website has only one Page, but it's quite long. To jump directly to other parts of the page I used anchor links.

The problem is that the anchor links don't jump far enough to the specific part. They go down but stop before they reach the right part.

I assume that the page is not fully loaded and it can't reach the specific part (it works if you scrolled trough the complete page before using the link).

Would there be any option to either:

- load the full page directly *or*
- when clicking on the anchor link, not jump but reload the side directly at the specific part

The link from weblow looks like this for example:

```html
<a href="#ceramics" style="color:rgb(27,27,27)" class="menubar_links">ceramics</a>
```

I tried using the link plus the anchor to reload instead of jump, but it didn't work:

```html
<a href="https://fabianpollex.com/#ceramics" style="color:rgb(27,27,27)" class="menubar_links">ceramics</a>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your questions accordingly and provide debugging details in the form of a [repro]. Linking to your website can only be considered as an advertisement, not as a replacement for details in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

### Your issue – Different website height without images

You have about 40 images lazy loading (loading when in they are in viewport). So if you visit the website, there is only the video and the text blocks visible. The browser determine the height of the webpage based on the text blocks, which are way shorter than with the sticky images next to them. It knows the real height (and so the correct scroll position to scroll to) if all images are loaded. With a scroll animation on anchor click, this leads to a full page scroll and the browser is loading all images in this 1second. Which leads to a different website height and a different scroll to position coordinate. Because it only knows the position at the time you click on the navigation, and it will not be recalculated as the website is fully loading.

### Possible solution – Set Aspect Ratios

You can use the [padding-hack](https://webflow.com/made-in-webflow/website/aspect-ratio-boxes) or use custom CSS and use the native [`aspect-ratio` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio).

```css
.detail-images img {
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
}
```

But you also have videos and portrait images, so you need to add classes to set 16:9 etc. image ratios.

Also, it looks like, your page is loading too much stuff on load.

According to [pagespeed](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-fabianpollex-com/pfsgd03530?form_factor=desktop) your video, which loads at first and with the highest priority is 14 MB big and should be max 5 MB and possible to lazy load as well.

I also found, that you are using `<form>` elements for the navigation. Which is a bit odd, and maybe you can change it to the following, to ensure native anchor scrolling working without delay.

From this:

```html
<form action="https://fabianpollex.com/#ceramics">
  <button style="background-color:transparent; color:rgb(27,27,27)" class="menubar_links" type="submit">ceramics</button>
</form>
```

to this:

```html
<a href="#ceramics" class="menubar_links" title="ceramics">ceramics</a>
```

But this will just to ensure native scroll behaviour. Maybe not fixing your bug.

Comment: Thank you so much for the Help! I now understand where the problem comes from. I will try your solutions and see if I can fix the problem.

As I wrote in my original text (It was edited out), I am an absolut beginner and thats why I tried the <form> solution. 
My thought was that it loads the page again, but at the right place. So no scrolling needed. But yes, thats just my dumb way to work around it.

So, thanks again for your help, much appreciated!